# How to use IIS WCF Host Service over internet when server is behind NAT

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I've waste xx hours for finding solution, but without success :(

I have IIS Server **behind NAT**, there is a WCF Service Host installed (on IIS). 
Localy and over LAN Communication client-WcfService working property, but when i try to add service reference (over internet) to my wcf service host - in visual studio, i have an issue as below:

> The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:

I have redirected on my router port WAN to port Lan of my WCF Sercice. Its working property because when i connect over internet to http://[...] .svc file in browser i can see proper site.
[image]

my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="KSPDJOBService.KSPDJOBService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="KSPDJOBService.IKSPDJOBService" />

    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/KSPDJOBService" />
       </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Any Ideas how to resolve my problem? i would be very thanksful for any tips.

Thanks.
Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue.

1st issue was: in port forwarding router has forwarding WAN port X to local port Y

2nd issue was: in svc/wsdl i had local url (thats why i had HTTP 400 error when trying to connect from internet)

SOLVED:

1st. So i've made forwarding WAN_port: Y to LAN_port: Y (the same ports)

2nd. I added in IIS Site - Binding hostname as WAN_domain_name.

Credits to : https://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/howto-fix-wcf-host-name-on-iis